# Update a single package – TeX Live (Windows)

Tags: packages, updating, texlive-2019

I have TeX Live 2019 on my computer and I need to update a single package, but TeX Live 2020 was already released a month ago, so I am getting such a message

```
tlmgr.pl: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2020).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

whenever I try to run `tlmgr update --all`

I was looking for the solution, but most seem to be outdated. Can you help me with such a problem?

Comment: point tlmgr to the historic repository `ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2019/tlnet-final`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, can you describe what I should do in details?

Comment: simply use the option `--repository `  with the above link, see the docu of tlmgr

Comment: @UlrikeFischer so I should simply run this command?
`tlmgr --repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2019/tlnet-final`

Comment: the documentation of tlmgr is here: https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I looked up the documentation, but there is no an example of a command I should run. Could you please add an answer here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108086/discussion-between-antshar-and-ulrike-fischer).

Comment: Run `tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2019/tlnet-final`.